# Making a volcano plot (with labels) using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to make a volcano plot using the script on this website (scroll down to get the volcano plot script): http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-texts-add-text-annotations-to-a-graph-in-r-software

but I end up with this error:

```
EM <- read.csv(file = "C:/Users/emlog.csv", header = TRUE)
EM$sig <- ifelse(EM$logpv < 0.05, "P-Value < 0.05", "Not Sig")
volcanoEM <- ggplot(EM, aes(x= logfc, y=logpv)) +  
  geom_point(aes(color=sig)) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "grey")) + 
  theme_bw(base_size = 12) +  
  theme(legend.position = "right") + 
  geom_text_repel(data = subset(EM, logpv < 0.05), aes(label = EM$rtmz), size=5, box.padding = unit(0.35, "lines"), point.padding = unit(0.3, "lines"))
plot(volcanoEM)
```

> Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (58): label, x, y

Not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: Please include sample data and make your issue reproducible.

Comment: Try replacing `aes(label = EM$rtmz)` with `aes(label = rtmz)` in `geom_text_repel()`?